# Redirection url:port to the same url:different-port

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I spent 5 days looking for both Google and here a solution but there must be something that escapes me or I do not understand and therefore I do not.

I will explain it in detail. I want to redirect all the requests of a url:port to the same url but with another port sameurl:port. Example: example.com:9717 to example.com:15617

I have tried various methods in .htaccess and with proxypass in the vhost without success.

Currently the requests are directed to:

myexample.com:9713/key-private/data

And I want to redirect all the traffic to a new port:

myexample.com:15617/key-private/data

The problem is that I can redirect the port with htaccess or proxypass but it does not redirect the private-key data, so when it receives the requests in the new port it gives an error indicating that the private-key does not exist or is not correct. I guess that's because the redirect does not send it, or it does not do it correctly. The private key is essential since without it the user can not access.

Could someone please tell me the solution or put me on the right path?

Examples that I have used:

```
NameVirtualHost IP:15617
<VirtualHost IP:15617> 
    ServerName example.com 
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/data
    ProxyRequests off 
    ProxyPass / http://IP:9713/ 
    ProxyPassReverse / http://IP:9713/  
</VirtualHost>

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com:9713$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^9713$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:15617/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^\/$
RewriteRule .* http://example.com:15617/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com:9713$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^9713$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:15617/$1 [L,R=302]

RewriteCond ${SERVER_PORT} 9713/$1
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com:15617/$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tried more options but I do not add them for not making the question too long. I know something escapes me, but I can not understand or find what it is.

Thank you very much and excuse my English, it is quite poor.

Answer (score 0):

On port 9713, you want *that* virtual host to redirect to port 15617, right? So something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:9713>
  ServerName example.com
  ServerAlias www.example.com
  RedirectMatch /(.*) http://www.example.com:15617/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I have tried it but it does not work, I have also tried some variations, and neither.

Anyway it will be very useful to investigate and maybe find the solution.

The same thing happens to me as with the other options I have shown, the port changes, but the key is not sent correctly and the communication fails.

Comment: This answer also only works if you know the server name, I'm trying to use it within a context where its answering to any server name (could be localhost, or the ip address) and unfortunately the server name is not available to Redirect, nor do you appear ot be able to redirect just to the port.